# Prove $Q[x]/(x^2+4)$ is isomorphic to $Q[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been asked to prove Q[x]/(x^2+4) is isomorphic to Q[x]/(x^2+1); I've looked at lots of similar solutions, but haven't been able to understand this. I know each ring is the quotient ring for their respective polynomials (the remainder when divided by x^2 + 4 or x^2 + 1), but what exactly does this mean in the context of isomorphisms? How can I prove that they are the "same"?

I've got x^2 = -4 in one ring and x^2 = -1 in another, but I don't know where to go from there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What can you say about $x^2+4$ and $x^2+1$ over Q? Are they reducible or irreducible? If they are irreducible, then the quotients are ..?

Comment: They're irreducible over Q, but then what can you say about the quotients? Is it not just like dividing a number by a prime number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+4)$ and $B=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Then $A=\mathbb Q[a]$ with $a^2=-4$ and $B=\mathbb Q[b]$ with $b^2=-1$.

Essentially, $A=\mathbb Q[2i]$ and $B=\mathbb Q[i]$.
So, just send $a \mapsto 2b$.

More precisely, the map $u+va \mapsto u+2vb$ is a ring isomorphism.

You just need to check that this map is a ring homomorphism because the inverse map is easy.

Comment: How do you get the intuition for this? If it were, say, any two polynomials, how could you see if it is isomorphic or not?

Comment: @Piepod, I've added a sentence about this specific case. The general case is harder of course.

Comment: So you've basically derived the ring's properties through x^2 = -4 and x^2 = -1 right? Basically, when Q[x] is divided by (x^2+4) and (x^2+1), x = 2i and x = i then?

Comment: @Piepod, exactly. Forget that these quotient rings are sets of cosets and use what quotient means: make something zero.